# How to make UINavigationBar Transparent in IOS 8?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have tried a lot to make UINavigationBar transparent. But I failed making it so.The image which I set was transparent. Here is my code .
Any help ?
Thanks in advance.

```
 [rootNavC.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NAV_BG_iphone.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
rootNavC.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
rootNavC.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                           UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor],
                     UITextAttributeTextShadowColor : [UIColor clearColor],
                    UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset : [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)],
                                UITextAttributeFont : [UIFont fontWithName:@"pastel" size:20]
 }];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks all. The thing is that I am adding this line in my view controller:

```
if (IS_OS_7_OR_LATER)
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

that is why the code is not working. When I remove the line

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

the code works.

Answer (score 15):

try this

```
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                         forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I hope the above code helps.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding this code. It worked for me in iOS 8.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]
```

Using this code, you don't even need to add your transparent `UIImage`. Update here if it helps you.

Comment: Can you show screenshot of navigation bar you getting with this code.

Answer (score 2):

@Sushil it seems like he has it. In my app, I use

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Instead of `alloc` `init`, is the only difference.

Comment: You'll need to remove the extra opening bracket if you're using this. Can't edit it since it's only a single character.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 [rootNavC.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NAV_BG_iphone.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  rootNavC.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
  [[rootNavC.UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
   //rootNavC.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                       UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor],
                 UITextAttributeTextShadowColor : [UIColor clearColor],
                UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset : [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)],
                            UITextAttributeFont : [UIFont fontWithName:@"pastel" size:20]
   }];
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on IOS 7 and +

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```